# How can I make setup.py include a package in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, git-submodules, setup.py

I have a library git repo `sub_lib` that I cannot publish directly to a pypi repository for various reasons. Instead I'm using it as a git submodule of another library `main_lib` in the following structure:

```
my_repo/
  setup.py
  main_lib/
    __init__.py
  sub_lib/  # a git submodule
    setup.py
    sub_lib/
      __init__.py
```

`main_lib` needs to `import sub_lib`, so how can I configure `my_repo`'s `setup.py` to include both `main_lib` and `sub_lib` as packages? In particular, is it possible to have `setup.py` include a package from a subdirectory (since it's in `sub_lib/sub_lib/`)?

Current setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
  name='main-lib',
  ...,
  packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
  package_data={'main_lib': ['py.typed'], 'sub_lib': ['py.typed']},
)
```

Or is it better to work around this by using a symlink?

Comment: Show your `setup.py`. You will probably need to work with `package_dir` argument of the `setuptools.setup()` function call.

Comment: This is basically it:
`from setuptools import setup, find_packages`

`setup(
    name='main-lib',
    ...,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
    package_data={'main_lib': ['py.typed'], 'sub_lib': ['py.typed']},
)`

Comment: Do not add it as a comment, edit your question to add your `setup.py` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with a symlink:

```
my_repo/
  setup.py
  main_lib/
    __init__.py
  sub_lib_repo/  # a git submodule
    setup.py
    sub_lib/
      __init__.py
  sub_lib -> ./sub_lib_repo/sub_lib
```

In my particular case, I needed `sub_lib` to also be a *pip* submodule of `main_lib`, which I was able get working with a 2nd symlink:

```
my_repo/
  setup.py
  main_lib/
    __init__.py
    sub_lib -> ../sub_lib_repo/sub_lib
  sub_lib_repo/  # a git submodule
    setup.py
    sub_lib/
      __init__.py
  sub_lib -> ./sub_lib_repo/sub_lib
```

In this way things like `from main_lib.sub_lib.foo import bar` work once `main_lib` is pip installed, and things like `from sub_lib.foo import bar` work (necessary imports within `sub_lib`). No changes to `setup.py` were required.